# How much Energy is Radiated by a gray body?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering, thermal-radiation

How much energy is radiated by a gray body at an ambient temperature of T Degrees Kelvin, between the wavelengths of w1 and w2 micrometers , if the emissivity of this gray body is 0.6 ? (Note:  Emissivity is a function of the geometry of the radiative surface , its physical properties, and the wavelength of the radiation emitted. For a perfect black body emissivity = 1. For a gray body emissivity should be between 0 and 1 ). According to the Stefan - Boltzmann Law of Radiation , the energy emitted by a body per second per unit area is proportional to the fourth power of the absolute temperature (measured in Kelvins ).

I am doing something wrong.  My calculations are as follows:
Energy1= Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength1 Energy2=Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength2 Energy1 - Energy2= 7.95 * 10^-20 Joules wavelength1= 2 micrometers wavelength2= 10 micrometers On the other hand epsilon * sigma * (absolute Temperature) ^4 gives me 326.5 Joules per second per meter squared if absolute temperature is about 313 Kelvin (about 40 Degrees Centigrade). 326.5 Joules per second per meter squared does not match 7.95 * 10^-20 Joules ( which is a few electron volts). Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: This looks like homework or an assignment. You need to show some effort towards a solution.

Comment: Energy1=Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength1

Comment: Energy1= Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength1       Energy2=Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength2        Energy1 - Energy2= 7.95 * 10^-20 Joules    wavelength1= 2 micrometers         wavelength2= 10 micrometers       On the other hand   epsilon * sigma * (absolute Temperature) ^4  gives me 326.5  Joules per second per meter squared  if  absolute temperature is about 313 Kelvin (about 40 Degrees Centigrade).

Comment: Energy1= Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength1       Energy2=Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength2        Energy1 - Energy2= 7.95 * 10^-20 Joules    wavelength1= 2 micrometers         wavelength2= 10 micrometers       On the other hand   epsilon * sigma * (absolute Temperature) ^4  gives me 326.5  Joules per second per meter squared  if  absolute temperature is about 313 Kelvin (about 40 Degrees Centigrade).   326.5 Joules per second per meter squared does not match 7.95 * 10^-20 Joules.  Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: @Solar Mike   Energy1= Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength1       Energy2=Planck's constant * speed of light / wavelength2        Energy1 - Energy2= 7.95 * 10^-20 Joules    wavelength1= 2 micrometers         wavelength2= 10 micrometers       On the other hand   epsilon * sigma * (absolute Temperature) ^4  gives me 326.5  Joules per second per meter squared  if  absolute temperature is about 313 Kelvin (about 40 Degrees Centigrade).   326.5 Joules per second per meter squared does not match 7.95 * 10^-20 Joules.  Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: Don't waste time putting useful information in comments. Put that in the original question.

Comment: How can you say quantities with different units do not match? There should be some king of conversion. I guess the small energy difference may be for one particle, whereas the radiation calculation is basically from 1 $m^2$ surface of grey body.